# Sourcing special-output-gates a.k.a complementary logic gates

Tags: logic-gates

[AllAboutCircuits](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-3/special-output-gates/) mentions that a suite of logic gates exist that provide both an inverted and non-inverted output from the standard collection of logic gates.

Is anyone aware of such a logic family and/or a place to source these components?

Comment: You mean like D flip-flops?

Comment: I mean special output AND, OR, NOT gates.  See linked article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do know of one such family, but you don't want to go there.

I'm referring to the 10k/100k ECL (Emitter-Coupled Logic) family. They were, in their day, the speed champions, able to operate at (gasp!) 100 MHz! Of course, this was back in the 70s and 80s. They were terrifically power-hungry, dissipating something like 50 mW/gate. But they were the fastest available, and the venerable CRAY-1 supercomputer was built using them.

Comment: Nowadays there are ECL relatives that run at ~5-10 GHz. CML is another related family that gives a complementary output "for free".

Comment: Also, ECL has high static power, but if you actually start switching the outputs, power doesn't increase as fast as it does with CMOS, so power consumption can be lower than in CMOS for high frequency designs.